# How much request volume can Microsoft Web Ngram API handle?

Tags: python-3.x, n-gram

I currently have a list of 200 words from which I need to create semantically correct permutations.  Unfortunately, permutating through a list of that size will lead to something like a trillion permutations.

What I am planning to do is utilize the Microsoft Web Ngram service and a yield function to find ngrams within my permutations that have joint scores above a certain threshold.  My hope here is that by filtering based on score, I will be left with only semantically correct permutations

My question is regarding the Microsoft Ngram API: with a list of 200 words, there will be A LOT of permutations to go through using this method -- can someone give me a sense if the api function be able to handle that volume of requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the number of queries you can make. However, the terms of use disallow threaded access, and the server response is relatively slow (between 0.12 and 0.22 s each query). So you could get at most 720k queries in a 24 hour period. I'm using PHP's file_get_contents(...). There may be a faster way.

In my application I've chopped up a library such that portions are updated with n-gram data as needed. It does slow down my code but it is at least tenable.

http://kkava.com/vocab/?ngram=on&imp=on&v=

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've edited my answer to be more direct.